# Need to change the port number from origin to another port number?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am newbie with Java and trying to code a very simple project java using springboot backend.

At Springboot-backend -> src/main/java -> net.javaguides.springboot.controler -> EMployeeController.java , I have this code

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

I thought that this code means when I open http://localhost:3000, the frontend I made will open.
And when I tried it, It opened, as I wish.

But when I changed it to `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3050")` and, I open http://localhost:3050, the frontend page does not open as I wish.

Could you please give me some ideas about my problem ? I am newbie and really want to study more. Thank you very much.

Comment: did you specified any port number in application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default port in the application.properties file by using

```
server.port = 8080  // port no. of your choice
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way as per my knowledge

1. you can use
   server.port = //port number like 8080
2. Go Run option there is an option of Edit Configurations click on the modify options and then in VM options section write
   -Dserver.port=//port number you want

[for more information click here](https://codedevstuff.blogspot.com/2015/05/change-port-on-spring-boot-application.html)